# SQL for update balance from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

i need help in updating a balance column in table. using update command

The balance column in present in customer_master

> customer_master > custcode,balance

It needs to be updated on the basis of values in two tables

> Bookings > custcode, bookingamount
>
> Receivables > custcode, amountrecd

for a customercode, the Balance is bookingamount - amountrecd

The command is to be applied in mysql and postgresql.

It can be for a single customer like (for custcode ='A1234XXXXX') and also may be applied for all customers present in customer_master.

*I tried Google on 'Updating balance from two tables' but with no luck so far.*

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my take which is sort of (possibly) over the top belt and braces

```
UPDATE  customer_master a
        LEFT JOIN (select custcode, sum(COALESCE(bookingamount, 0)) AS bookingamount 
                   from bookings group by custcode) b
            ON a.custcode = b.custcode
        LEFT JOIN (select custcode, sum(COALESCE(amountrecd, 0)) AS amountrecd 
                   from receivables group by custcode) c
            ON a.custcode = c.custcode
SET     
         a.balance = COALESCE(b.bookingamount, 0) - COALESCE(c.amountrecd, 0) 
-- WHERE a.custcode = 'A1234XXXXX'
```

Comment: thanks and any suggestions for optimizations, it takes a while to update

Comment: Indexes will be your friends here on custcode An index on CustCode and  bookingamount on bookings and custcode and bookingamount on receivables. This will make the dube queries extremely fast, and you can then choose to have a index on master. I would for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

For MySQL, you can join multiple tables even if it is an `UPDATE` statement. I used `LEFT JOIN` because there are possibilities wherein `custcode` doesn't have a record yet on `receivables` tables.

```
UPDATE  customer_master a
        LEFT JOIN bookings b
            ON a.custcode = b.custcode
        LEFT JOIN receivables c
            ON a.custcode = c.costcode
SET     a.balance = COALESCE(b.bookingamount, 0) - COALESCE(c.amountrecd, 0) 
-- WHERE a.custcode = 'A1234XXXXX'
```

*follow-up question: can custcode contains multiple records on `bookings` and `receivables`? If so, I'll update the answer.*

Comment: +1 for the left joins! I would also group and sum the the children by cust code, to deal with the case where there are multiple amounts in the child tables

Comment: @PreetSangha I agree that's why i ask the OP if it has a possibility that it can contain multiple records for a single `custcode`. hehe

Comment: True - but it's a safer more general solution to do it that way.

Comment: thanks and yes, there are multiple occurances of custcode in both child taables

Comment: Please see @PreetSangha answer. The update would look like that. You need to have a subquery that computes it total value.